# How to concatenate stdin in to a pipe?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to send the output of a pipe and stdin to a pipe in bash.

I.e:

```
gen_input | cat - | parse_input_and_stdin
```

would send the output of `gen_input` to `parse_input_and_stdin` and then leave stdin open for more interactive input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cat <(gen_input) - | parse_input_and_stdin
```

Comment: This came great for testing my `post-receive` hook ;) As I needed to feed it
with `$from`, `$to`, and `$branch` respectively, I did:
`cat <(git log -2 --format=oneline --reverse | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ')
- | ./hooks/post-receive`, additionally supplying branch by typing it, then
  CTRL+D. Great! `;)`.

Comment: Very useful! This helped me in feeding a program with some known input then continue on feeding it from the stdin in an interactive mode. Thanks this nice gem!

Answer (score 19):

Close.

```
{ gen_input ; cat ; } | parse_input_and_stdin
```

Comment: This also works, but I chose the other one because it works more obviously.

Comment: This form makes it simpler to concatenate the output of more than two sources, though. Just keep adding them between semi-colons.